# Django: Return serializer ValidationError in Model save() method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I use django-rest-framework to create Rest API within Django framework. And it's possible to return any `validationError` beside serializer methods.

But, I was wondering is it possible to return errors from `save()` method of django **model** that be translated to django rest `validationError`?

For example imagine I want to limit creating objects on a specific table. like this:

```
class CustomTable(models.Model):
    ... # modles fields go here

    def save():
        if CustomTable.objects.count() > 2:
             # Return a validationError in any serializer that is connected to this model.
```

**Note** I could use `raise ValueError` or `raise ValidationError`, but they all cause 500 error on endpoint. But i want to return a response in my api view that says for example 'limit reached'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DRF `ValidationError` is handled in the serializer so you should catch any expected errors when calling your model's save method and use it to raise a `ValiddationError`.

For example, you could do this in your serializer's save method:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    try:
        super().save(**kwargs)
    except ModelError as e:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(e)
```

Where `ModelError` is the error you're raising in your model

Answer (score 1):

There's are two to three ways to do this

1.Using [clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method.

```
class CustomTable(models.Model):
    ... # modles fields go here

    def clean(self):
     if CustomTable.objects.count() > 2:
                raise ValidationError(_('custom table can not have more than two entries.'))
```

2. Using [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders).

   ```
   @receiver(pre_save, sender= CustomTable)
   def limit(sender, **kwargs):
         if CustomTable.objects.count() > 2:
               raise ValidationError(_('Custom table can not have more than two entries.'))
   ```

Comment: Signals is always better. Cauz it handles objects created in Django admin.