# Django rest framework - ValidationError raised in models' save method. How to pass error to http response

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-validation

I'm using the django rest framework, with a ModelViewset:

```
class FooViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
```

and a ModelSerializer:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = [
            "id",
            "bar",
            "baz",
        ]
```

I also have the model's save method:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self):
        if condition:
            raise ValidationError("Illegal parameters")
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When this validation error is triggered, drf, sends a 500 response to the frontend, with no text. How do I get it to instead give a 'bad request' response, with the text in the ValidationError (Illegal parameter)?

Comment: return httpresponse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Return serializer ValidationError in Model save() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061030/django-return-serializer-validationerror-in-model-save-method)

Comment: It's important to use `ValidationError` from `rest_framework.exceptions`. If you use `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError` you get response 500 error, instead of 400.

Answer (score 9):

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class Foo(models.Model):
...
    def save(self):
        if condition:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Illegal parameters")
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have not tested this.

Instead, I would recommend doing this inside your serializer class's `create` method.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = [
            "id",
            "bar",
            "baz",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if condition:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Illegal parameters")
        instance = super(FooSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your custom error, like this:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

class MyError(APIException):
    """Readers error class"""
    def __init__(self, msg):
        APIException.__init__(self, msg)
        self.status_code = HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        self.message = msg
```

And return any status code what you want.

You can use it normally where you want like this:

```
raise MyError({"detail": "You did something wrong!"})
```