# How to write unit test ValidationError case in response by use client.post()?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-validation

I have a model with a time validator `raise ValidationError('End time cannot be earlier than start time')`

So I want to write a unit test using `client.post()` with data invalid (from_time > to_time), and I expected ValidationError to appear in this test.

```
    raise ValidationError('End time cannot be earlier than start time')
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['End time cannot be earlier than start time']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take a look at the document example on how to write test case https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#example. In your case it would be like so(notice that this is just an example, so modify to fit your case):

This is for validating from serializer/api of DRF:

```
import unittest
from django.test import Client
import datetime

class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs a client.
        self.client = Client()

    def test_invalid_date(self):
        # Issue a POST request.
        response = self.client.post(
                   '/your/path/url',
                   {
                      'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17), 
                      'end_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15) #notice end_time smaller than start_time
                   },
              )

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 400)

        # Check that the rendered context json have error message.
        self.assertEqual(response.json()['key']['path']['to']['error']['message'], 'End time cannot be earlier than start time')
```

This is for validating from model validator([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)):

for example you have your model validator like so in your model:

```
def custom_validator(value):
    if value.end_time < value.start_time:
      raise ValidationError('End time cannot be earlier than start time')
```

Your unit test will be like this, use python `assertRaisesRegex()` to check for python ValidationError type:

```
import unittest
from django.test import Client
import datetime

class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_invalid_date(self):
        with self.assertRaisesRegex(ValidationError, 'End time cannot be earlier than start time'):
             your_model = YourModel(
               start_time=datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17), 
               end_time=datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15) 
             )
             your_model.full_clean()
```

Comment: My code stopped at the validator in models.py. So response doesn't get back!

Comment: @HuyNguyen i have updated the answer with option to validate for ValidationError

Comment: Thank you for being so patient, I just want to testing API and get a response to indicate for the front-end that error. But in my case, it stopped in the validator in the model, so any way to solve it?

Comment: @HuyNguyen Because you have a validator inside of your models, it will raise a python error. The only way to check for this is the second option I mentioned. But if you want to test on the API side, you have to do manual validation on the view/serializer size to return it from the API(after that you can go with option 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651511/django-rest-framework-validationerror-raised-in-models-save-method-how-to-pa

Comment: I tried to write a validator for my code before time. When I used API for creating Instances, the validator is work well, but if I use the admin site for an update or to create an instance, the validator in this case ignored!

Comment: @HuyNguyen yes that because the Django admin only check for the model validator functions, if you write the validator on the view/api side, the admin can't check that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247052/discussion-between-huy-nguyen-and-linh-nguyen).

Answer (score 1):

When using [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) your test would look as simple as this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def test_error_when_to_time_before_from_time(db, admin_client):
    invalid_data = {
        "from_time": datetime.today(),
        "to_time": datetime.today() - timedelta(days=2),
    }
    response = admin_client.post("<url-to-endpoint>", data=invalid_data)
    assert response.status_code == 400
    assert "End time cannot be earlier than start time" in response.content.decode()
```

Pytest-django gives you a logged in admin client and creates a temporary database depending on your current migrations for every test. After the test the changes are discarded again.

I also added `"TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT": "json",` to the `REST_FRAMEWORK` dictionary in `settings.py`.