# Convert Validationerror to serializers.Validationerror in Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a following problem.
I have a model level validation which checks data consistency on each save. 
In serializers, if this model level validation works, it produces `server error 500` with trace-back, whereas `serializer.Validationerror` in serializer produces nice and clean `400 error` with error message in json.

In order to convert model level `Validationerror` to `serializers. Validationerror` I use following code in my serializers.

```
def perform_create(self, validated_data):
    try:
        return super().perform_create(validated_data)
    except exceptions.ValidationError as err:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            f'Model level validation assertion -- {str(err)}'
        ) from err
```

It works, but I cant and don’t want to override  each and every one serializer to convert  `Validationerror` to `serializers. Validationerror`.

Question is  - is it any way to catch  all Validationerror  and convert them to serializers. Validationerrors?

Comment: Great question and answer. It would have been great if this very specific scenario was handled by DRF. I'm surprised to see this not bothering many. In [another response here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54061446/399435) it was mentioned to directly raise the `ValidationError` from `rest_framework.exceptions` as opposed to the one in `django.core.exceptions` when implementing validations in the model. This also seems to work very well for both the API and performing operations directly against the model. It also keeps the code DRY by not having to repeat validations in the serializer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from rest_framework.response import Response as DRF_response
from rest_framework import status

from django.core import exceptions
from django.views import View
from django.http import response


def custom_exception_handler(exc: Exception, context: View) -> [response, None]:

    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if isinstance(exc, exceptions.ValidationError):
        data = exc.message_dict
        return DRF_response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, )

    return response
```

I made a custom error handler which catches all Django standard Validation errors and return DRF style reponse on them.

Comment: How do you pass the View when you use the custom_exception_handler